# Multiple tables with same type of objects in Room database

Tags: android, sql, database, database-design, android-room

I'm using Room as the database for the app. I have a scenario where an `Object` of a certain type needs to be stored in separate tables. As an example, lets take the `Object` called `Book.java`

Now, I want to have two SQL tables:

- Books_Read
- Books_To_Read

*ignore any naming conventions for SQL DB please - this is just an example*

**Problem**

Normally, one would just use `@Entity(tableName = "Books_Read")` in the `Book.java` class and have a `DAO` class that will use that table name.

The thing is; how would I then be able to use the same `Book.java` class to store in the `Books_To_Read` table? Since I already defined `@Entity(tableName = "Books_Read")` as part of the `Book.java` class and I see no where to define the `Books_To_Read` table for the `Book.java` class

The only solution I was able to come up with, which seems a little hackery and unnessasery, was to create a new class - let's call it `BookToRead.java`  that extends `Book.java` and define `@Entity(tableName = "Books_To_Read")` in the class.

**Question**

Is there a better way to do this or is this the expected way to handle it?

Comment: I mean if it's the same entity - why do you want to have different tables for this then? Imo it should be the same table but just with additional column like "to_read" or whatever.

Comment: @rom4ek You're right. I realised this soon after posting this question. I eventually solved it by having one table and a new column added to differentiate between he different types.

Comment: I am not sure if this is only related to this particular case, but having an extra field / column to the table telling if the book was read or not, won't do the job? Why you want them stored in different tables ?

Comment: i have a similar issue. data can become stale after 24 hours so i delete all the saved data after this time. therefore, ill delete weather i have favourited the object on delete (deleting boolean varibale stored in the obj). therefore i potentially need another table and or flag in shared prefs. currently using room aswell.

Answer (score 40):

> Is this the expected way to handle it?

**No**. It is a wrong approach. You should **eliminate duplication of data** for several reasons.

- It will cost storage space. As the size of database increases, this
  will began to become worse.
- It will make the system complicated. If you are updating a single
  field, You may have to perform the same action at different places.
  If you miss any one of them, the entire data will become
  inconsistent. It is possible to perform such operations as
  a single transaction. But it is always better to keep the database structure 
  clean.

## Solution

**Method 1: Introduce new tables**

You can store details of books in only one table say `"Books"`. `"Books_To_Read"` or any other table should contain only the reference to the `"Books"` table (*By using the id/ primary key in `"Books"` table*). You can then use the `JOIN` keyword to get the entire record at a single query.

This method is preferred if each type (read and unread books in this case) has it's own set of fields (*Like the read_date, read_time for read books and wish_to_read for unread books*).

**Method 2: Introduce new field**

You can simply add a new type which specifies the type. In this case, there are only two type(read and unread), a boolean field (something like `is_read`) will be fine.

This would be the easiest method. But this will work only if you just want to indicate which type the row belongs to. If you do need to store type specific data and you introduce additional fields for that purpose, remember that those fields will exists for others types too.

Comment: I understood and liked method 2 very much. But I'm having trouble understanding method 1. Can you explain it a bit more with an example or link me to a suitable documentation?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I eventually solved this problem:

I added an ID to the `Book.java` class that represents whether it has been read or not. Backed by an `EnumType` that was either `book_read` or `book_unread` and then in my `DAO` for `"BooksDataTable"` I then just use a `SQL query` to `select` the `ID` I want. So by changing the query I can get either all the `books_read` or `books_to_read` or `all_books`. This way, there is no duplication of data and everything is in one table, without having to use `JOIN` or `OneToMany` relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I was writing sample app when Ahamad gave his answer.

> [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow fluent
>   database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite.

main idea is same as of to store Book data in one table and use the id of the book in other tables. 
have a look at my sample [project](https://github.com/sahilmanchanda2/AndroidRoomTest)

result of logcat

```
02-19 16:39:26.741 10520-10520/com.example.jingged.roomtest E/MainActivity: Book{id = 1 name = Book 0, author Author 0}
02-19 16:39:26.741 10520-10520/com.example.jingged.roomtest E/MainActivity: Book{id = 2 name = Book 1, author Author 1}
02-19 16:39:26.741 10520-10520/com.example.jingged.roomtest E/MainActivity: Book{id = 3 name = Book 2, author Author 2}
02-19 16:39:26.741 10520-10520/com.example.jingged.roomtest E/MainActivity: Book{id = 4 name = Book 3, author Author 3}
02-19 16:39:26.767 10520-10520/com.example.jingged.roomtest E/MainActivity: BookToRead Book{id = 3 name = Book 2, author Author 2}
02-19 16:39:26.767 10520-10520/com.example.jingged.roomtest E/MainActivity: BookToRead Book{id = 4 name = Book 3, author Author 3}
02-19 16:39:26.768 10520-10520/com.example.jingged.roomtest E/MainActivity: BooksRead Book{id = 1 name = Book 0, author Author 0}
02-19 16:39:26.768 10520-10520/com.example.jingged.roomtest E/MainActivity: BooksRead Book{id = 2 name = Book 1, author Author 1}
```

Comment: This just copy the same code and change the table name only?