# How to have few tables with one entity in Android room?

Tags: java, android, android-room

Its easy to create Entity and corresponding table in room. Assume we have a User entity.

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
public class User {

@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "userid")
@NonNull
private String mId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "username")
private String mUserName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "last_update")
private Date mDate;
```

The data will be stored in table "users" by default. Can I keep the same entity but having 2 tables at the same time? E.g. "old_users" and "users"

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279481/multiple-tables-with-same-type-of-objects-in-room-database/48864379#48864379) will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly. Entities have a 1:1 mapping to tables.

You could use Java inheritance to minimize code duplication and support multiple tables (e.g., `User` and `OldUser` inheriting from `BaseUser`).

Comment: What if someone's using data class on Kotlin where all fields are passed through the main constructor and the class has no extra methods, how can we minimize duplication ?

Comment: @TamimAttafi: Minimize *what* duplication? I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you can explain in greater detail what you are looking for. To be honest, while my answer is technically correct, IMHO the better answer is "do not have an `old_users` table -- have an `isOld` property on `User`".